# Having an issue while binding data to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ienumerable

I have a model

```
public class ItemHistory
{
    public int TotalItems;
    public int ScannedItems;
    public int PendingItems;
}
```

on button click event i want to load a grid depending on that values.
The code for Button_Click

```
int TotalItems = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);
int ScannedItems = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);

int PendingItems = TotalItems - ScannedItems;
List<ItemHistory> ih = new List<ItemHistory>();
ih.Add(new ItemHistory
{TotalItems, ScannedItems, PendingItems});
gvrecap.DataSource = ih;
gvrecap.DataBind();
```

But, it gives me an error of the below:

> Cannot initialize type 'ConsignmentCreation.ItemHistory' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Could not understand it. Please help...Thanks in advance

Thanks for the solution, but I now i am facing a new kind of problem in `Databind();`

> A field or property with the name 'TotalItems' was not found on the selected data source.

The below is the Gridview arrangement:

```
                                                  <asp:GridView ID="gvrecap" runat="server"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="25" Width="741px">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalItems" HeaderText="TotalItems" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ScannedItems" HeaderText="ScannedItems" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50" />
                                 <asp:BoundField DataField="PendingItems" HeaderText="PendingItems" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="50" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You cannot bind using a list, as that implements IEnumerable, whereas ItemHistory does not. Have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4de439ac-80f8-4037-a37a-ba7ec29a024d/bind-list-in-gridview?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Edit your columns, select the TotalItems column and ensure that in the section "Design" that the (Name) is spelled correctly. Do the same for the "Data" section and ensure that the "DataPropertyName" is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for initializing your list with a new ItemHistory object is not quite right. You need to specify the field name and value.

```
            int pendingItems = 10;
            int scannedItems = 5;
            int totalItems = 15;

            List<ItemHistory> ih = new List<ItemHistory>();

            ih.Add(new ItemHistory
            {
               PendingItems = pendingItems, 
               ScannedItems = scannedItems, 
               TotalItems = totalItems
            });
```

The above works. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use the object initializer properly. 
Try this (not tested):

```
int totalItems = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);
int scannedItems = Convert.ToInt32(lblItemsScanned.Text);

int pendingItems = totalItems - scannedItems;
List<ItemHistory> ih = new List<ItemHistory>();
ih.Add(new ItemHistory
{TotalItems = totalItems, ScannedItems = scannedItems , PendingItems = pendingItems });
gvrecap.DataSource = ih;
gvrecap.DataBind();
```

I reccomend using Properties in your model instead of variables for that purpose like so :

```
public class ItemHistory
{
    public int TotalItems {get;set;}
    public int ScannedItems {get;set;}
    public int PendingItems {get;set;}
}
```